# Can the template/CSS of the Swagger plugin for ServiceStack be customized?

Tags: servicestack, swagger

When using the Swagger plugin for ServiceStack, is it possible to customize the HTML/CSS template for the Swagger UI page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See ServiceStack's Swagger Docs for how to [override Swaggers Embedded Resources](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api#overriding-swaggers-embedded-resources):

ServiceStack's [Virtual File System](http://docs.servicestack.net/virtual-file-system) supports multiple file source locations where you can override Swagger's embedded files by including your own custom files in the same location as the existing embedded files. This lets you replace built-in ServiceStack embedded resources with your own by simply copying the [/swagger-ui](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger/swagger-ui) files you want to customize and placing them in your Website Directory at:

```
/swagger-ui
  /css
  /images
  /lib
  index.html
```